# Redirect back using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mobile

I just .htaccess to redirect users to the mobile site using this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} "android|blackberry|ipad|iphone|ipod|iemobile|opera  mobile|palmos|webos|googlebot-mobile" [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://m.mysite.com/ [L,R=302]
##end mobile redirect
```

but what I'm looking for now is to be able to redirect users back to the pc site when they click on the "back to homepage link" on the mobile site
Any way to do this using .htaccess ?

Comment: Never Mind.
I found the answer I just added
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www\.m.site\.com [NC]
before the code and it worked :)

Comment: Instead of "never mind", why not just click the delete link below the Q?   :-)

Comment: What happens if after they clicked the "back to homepage" links they follow some other link on the normal page? Then the referrer is `www.site.com` and he get redirect to the mobile site again. Also referrer is not always available, as some (mobile-)proxies remove them.